# use css attribute with hyphen while using inputProps of TextField object in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

so im trying to customize a TextField component in material-ui,
and i read about the inputProps attribute which can help me center the text, unfortunately i tried something like this:

```
<TextField
  required
  id="userName"
  label="User name:"
  defaultValue="enter your user name"
  margin="normal"
  fullWidth={true}
  inputProps={{ textAlign: 'center', }}
/>
```

but than i get an error about textAlign prop, it won't convert from camelCase into a hyphen case text-align, and i can't write text-align instead because its invalid... what can i do?

heres the error:
React does not recognize the `textAlign` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `textalign` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

thanks alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a quoted property name:

```
<TextField
     required
     id="userName"
     label="User name:"
     defaultValue="enter your user name"
     margin="normal"
     fullWidth={true}
     inputProps={{"text-align": 'center',}}
 />
```

Notice the `{"text-align": 'center',}` on the last line. The left-hand side (name) of a property initializer can be quoted (single or double quotes) if the name won't be a valid identifier (in your case, because of the hyphen).

Simpler example:

```js
var obj = {
  "name-with-hyphen": 42
};
console.log(obj["name-with-hyphen"]); // 42
```

Comment: thank you very much, i really didn't know about that escaping... do you know how i can inject the style attribute with text-align:center as property? because right now text-align:center doesn't work because if you want to style an input component you must inejct it into his style property as i see now...

Comment: never mind, i played with it alittle and found how to do that: inputProps={{"style":{textAlign:"center"}}}